# html float right set the span in new line

Tags: html, css

How to set two span inline in opera, where the html this:

```
<section id="board-sub-header">
            <span>
                <span class="left">Text</span>
            </span>
            <span style="float:right"> 
                <a href="#" class="image-link application-icon popup-link">
                    Applications
                </a>
            </span>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#board-sub-header span { float: left; width: 50%; display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EKQkS/